# execCommand('Italic") issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm trying to make use of `execCommand` as I thought it is enough for my purpose, but when testing it under IE 8, there is strange thing: only 'italic' options fails to revert (I can set italic but it wont go off for the next `execCommand` call), or rather the browser cannot recognise that italic was already applied, because when run `queryCommandState('italic', false, null))` I receive `false`. Thing is, that there is problem only with italic other looks ok(actually check couple;-)). 
There is another point that I use `contentEditable` on html element, when I moved it to iframe it worked but I really do not want to use iframes. Furthermore there is `styleWithCSS` command to force styling html by style attribute rather than by tags like `b` -> `style="font-weight: bold"  But this of course doesn't work in IE too.

Could you please advise or maybe suggest some other tool to handle some basic text editing in html

update: I just run command in js:

`document.execCommand(actionToCall,false, args);`

it correctly format selected text in my `contentEditable`:

```
<div contenteditable="true" type="text" class="myeditor-editable" style="white-space:pre-wrap">
    <i>test</i>
</div>
```

but seccond call do nothing -> it actually tries to append `<i></i>` again. ( when look at HTML bar in FF console, then I see that there is some manipulation with html but like I said it stays italic)

Edit2: It looks that there must be a conflict in my code as in fiddle it's working(http://jsfiddle.net/kpskxfbo/1/ ), I thought that can be because the result in jsfiddle is returned in iframe but I have try it on my local computer and it looks fine too... I will post update once I found the problem.

Comment: Please show a testable piece of code.

Comment: please show an example of issue in jsfiddle (or like this)

Comment: @eldi I agree with you, it's very annoying